# ASP.NET Identity - using roles as predefined claim sets

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm new to ASP.NET Identity, but from what I've read, my task should be realizable with it.

I'm thinking of combining **roles** and **claims** in a way that

- **Roles** are used as an *abstract* description of what a user's function in the company is ("admin", "sales", "support", etc.)
- **Claims** are used as *concrete* statements of what its owner is allowed to do ("create user", "edit support request", "reset password")
- Multiple **claims** are assigned to **roles**, representing a "permission set" that reflect each role's permissions.
- Resources are protected by policies that can require a role or a claim

Is that generally a viable way to use ASP.NET Identity?

I found a promising approach here: http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims which pretty much looks like the base for what I need and where the blogger is using `RoleManager.AddClaimAsync()` to add claims to roles. However, the function doesn't seem to be part of the latest `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` Nuget package v2.2.1 from February 2015, while it is implemented here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/RoleManager.cs
Am I mixing something up here?

Comment: Technically, roles should be permissions: "create user" etc. Most devs use roles incorrectly, and Microsoft doesn't help by conflating them with "groups", such as in the case of Windows Auth. Claims should be transient data associated with a "user". They are most applicable when there's no actual "user" object (i.e. record in a database), such as when doing OAuth. If you have a user record, it's generally preferable to attach the data along with that.

Comment: Link to github you quote is for .Net Core, Identity v3, next generation. Version 2.2.1 is here: aspnetidentity.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3):

When you look at *[System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)*, Role is one of ClaimTypes. Basically, Role is a subset of Claim.

It all depends on how you plan to use them. If you use default ***Authorize*** filter, you will need to add them as ***ClaimTypes.Role***. Look at `claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));` in the following example.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
    private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

    public CustomAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SignIn(User user, IList<string> roleNames)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
        };

        foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
        }

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

### Opinion

I *personally* do not like creating custom Claim names such as "create user", "edit support request", "reset password".

Instead, I'll just keep them as Role such as `User-Create`, `User-Edit`, `User-Delete`, so that I can use Authorize attribute.

Comment: `ClaimTypes.Role` sounds reasonable to use, thanks for that. Still, what I missed in all examples I came around and what I am unsure about, is the combination of *concrete permissions* like `User-Create`, `User-Edit` and *abstract, named permission "sets" or "templates"* like `Editor` or `Admin`, which are essentially collections of the former concrete permissions. That sounds like a very common requirement to me, so I had expected Identity framework to come up with it out of the box. Having said that, I might just be blind to the obvious.